# Javascript Quardratic equation solver BUG - need explanation

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm doing a quardratic equation solver on Html+Javascript using the solution of

[image: Quardratic solving equation]

In my html form I got 3 textbox stand for a,b,c in ax^2+bx+=0 , with 3 comcobox(option) for setting the a,b,c to be + or - as shown in

[image]

I managed to recieve the signs +,- by triggerd these functions when the combobox are changed

```
  function changeasign()
    {
       signa=document.getElementById("signa").value;
    }
  function changebsign()
    {
       signb=document.getElementById("signb").value;
    }
  function changecsign()
    {
       signc=document.getElementById("signc").value;
    }
```

Then when the button is pressed this functio is called

```
   function cal()
     {
       var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
       if(a=="")
       {
         a=1;
       }
       var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
       if(b=="")
       {
         b=1;   
       }
       var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
       if(c=="")
       {
         c=0;
       }
       var first;
       var rawdis;
       var dis;
       var divide;
       var x1;
       var x2;
       if(signa=="+" && signb=="+" && signc=="+")// +,+,+
       {
         first=-b;
         rawdis=Math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c;
         if(rawdis<0)
         {
           document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "This equation doesn't have realnumber as answers";
           return;
         }
         dis=Math.sqrt(rawdis);
         divide=2*a;
         x1=(first+dis)/divide;
         x2=(first-dis)/divide;
         document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "X="+x1+","+x2;
         }
       else if(signa=="+" && signb=="+" && signc=="-")
       {
    //Loops through +,+,-   +,-,+   +,-,-
```

This work fine , If I input +1x^2+2x+1  it will returns X=-1,-1

THE PROBLEMS COMES: Any of the if,else if that contain signb=="-" Gives first answer worng but gives second answer correctly

Thiscase:

```
    else if(signa=="+" && signb=="-" && signc=="+")
      {
        first=b;
        rawdis=Math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c;
        if(rawdis<0)
        {
          document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "This equation doesn't have realnumber as answers";
          return;
        }
         dis=Math.sqrt(rawdis);
         divide=2*a;
         x1=(first+dis)/divide;
         x2=(first-dis)/divide;
         document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "X="+x1+","+x2;
      }
```

Input : +x^2-6x+9    Output: X=30,3    Correct answer: X=3,3

When I set it to display all the variables   Output: first=6; rawdis=0; dis=0; divide=2; x1=30; x2=3;  How does x1 become 30?

Also with all others that have B sign as "-" are giving out wrong answers on x1 without any pattern even all previous variable are correct!!! Now I fix it by reflect it to the other side of equation and calculate out of that equation

ax^2-bx+c=0 into -ax^2+bx-c=0 This works. But I just want to know why does this bug exist? It shouldn't because it's a simple maths

Comment: please, take a moment to edit your post and format that code properly. If you want us to help, at least make it easy to read your code, and use normal writing instead of >>> and <<< and four question marks. We're just regular people here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry for that, I'm fixing my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the javascript's loose typing. It thinks that `b` is an string so when it tries to do `first+dis` rather than adding numerically is does string concatenation `"6"+"0"` gives `"60"`. Its smart enough to convert to a numerical format in all other operations.

To solve this uses

```
a = parseFloat(a);
b = parseFloat(b);
c = parseFloat(c);
```

p.s. you code will be a lot tidier if you find the signed versions of a, b, c

```
if(signa=="-")
   a = -a;
```

that way you can eliminate all the repeated code in the if statements.

Comment: Wow thanks!! It works. I'm not really familiar  with javascript variables Xb. Anyway Thank you very much